# How to cancel "Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue"

Tags: excel, vba

In my code:

```
Sub bouttonPause()
Pauz = MsgBox("Do you want to stop the loop?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Stop")
End sub

Sub startSAbutton()
Pauz = vbNo
Call SA
End sub

Sub SA()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'If user didnt click on pauz button
If Pauz <> vbYes Then

--things

'# Restart macro every 15 minutes

        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "SA"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, it's a loop that restarts the macro every 15 minutes. If you want to stop this loop, you click on a pause button so Pauz = vbYes and this "if" cannot be "trigered"

```
If Pauz <> vbYes Then
```

However, if a user starts the macro at let's say 8 AM:

At 08:15 there will be a restart of the macro, same for 08:30, 08:45 etc

Now let's say that at 08:21 users clicks on Pause button and chooses Yes option, at 08:30 the macro will not launch

But if at 08:27 he clicks on the startSAbutton, Pauz will be vbNo and:

- A loop will start from 08:27 and will loops every 15 minutes
- The loop of 08:30, 08:45 etc will resume as now Pauz = vbNo

In other words, how can I cancel the first loop and be sure that it will not launch anymore before starting another loop

EDIT: clarifications
To shorten my problem:

- I click on bouttonPause: pauz = no, loop is launched every 15 minutes
- I click on startSAbutton: pauz = yes, loop will not start at the next occurence and the
- **BUT:** if I click on pausebutton to loop#1 then click on startSAbutton to star loop#2 the pauz variable will be no then yes so when the next loop#1 will try to launch at the next occurence it will succeed because now pauz = yes. I will then have two loops running. That's what I want to prevent, I want it so when I start a new loop it cancels the previous loop.

Please excuse my poor English and thanks for reading.
Have a good day !

Comment: Replace your line `--do things` with `Else` ? And make sure the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` comes after `End If` in case the if statement doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Do you press that button while `SA` runs? Was `Pauz` been declared on top of the module (in the declarations area)? Otherwise, it is a local variable, valid only in the `Sub`  it was born, which means nothing for `startSAbutton`. Please, writhe `Option Explicit` on top of all your modules. This will oblige you to declare all variables, as it should be better.

Comment: I might havent explained well my problem, everything is declared as it should and everything works in 90% of the time. I've edited my first post so you can understand

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution:

```
Sub startSAbutton()
If NextSA <> "00:00:00" Then Application.OnTime NextSA, "SA", , False
Pauz = vbNo
Call SA
End sub

Sub SA()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'If user didnt click on pauz button
If Pauz <> vbYes Then

--things

'# Restart macro every 15 minutes
        NextSA = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
        Application.OnTime NextSA, "SA"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

Therefore I "unschedule" the instruction programmed at NextSA